# Counting concurrent records based on startdate and enddate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-date-functions

The table structure:

StaffingRecords

- PersonnelId int
- GroupId int
- StaffingStartDateTime datetime
- StaffingEndDateTime datetime

How can I get a list of staffing records, given a date and a group id that employees belong to, where the count of present employees fell below a threshold, say, 3, at any minute of the day?

The way my brain works, I would call a stored proc repeatedly with each minute of the day, but of course this would be horribly inefficient:

```
SELECT COUNT(PersonnelId) 
FROM DailyRosters 
WHERE GroupId=@GroupId 
    AND StaffingStartTime <= @TimeParam 
    AND StaffingEndTime > @TimeParam 
    AND COUNT(GroupId) < 3
GROUP BY GroupId
HAVING COUNT(PersonnelId) < 3
```

Edit: If it helps to refine the question, employees may come and go throughout the day.  Personnel may have a staffing record from 0800 - 0815, and another from 1000 - 1045, for example.

Comment: Well, you don't need to check every minute of the day, just the moments <  any StaffingStartTime and greater than > StaffingEndTime. So, if you put all of those into a table, you could begin selecting all the counts for those moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution where I find all of the distinct start and end times, and then query to see how many other people are clocked in at the time. Everytime the answer is less than 4, you know you are understaffed at that time, and presumably until the NEXT start time.

```
with meaningfulDtms(meaningfulTime, timeType, group_id)
as
(  
    select distinct StaffingStartTime , 'start' as timeType, group_id
    from DailyRosters 
    union
    select distinct StaffingEndTime , 'end' as timeType, group_id
    from DailyRosters 
)

select COUNT(*), meaningfulDtms.group_id, meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
from DailyRosters  dr
inner join meaningfulDtms on dr.group_id = meaningfulDtms.group_id
and (
 (dr.StaffingStartTime  < meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
     and dr.StaffingEndTime  >= meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
     and meaningfulDtms.timeType = 'start')
 OR
 (dr.StaffingStartTime  <= meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
     and dr.StaffingEndTime  > meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
     and meaningfulDtms.timeType = 'end')
)
group by meaningfulDtms.group_id, meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
having COUNT(*) < 4
```

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but could you explain what meaningfulDtms(meaningfulTime, timeType, group_id) is, and how to create it?  I'm using SQL Server 2008R2.

Comment: It's just a CTE (Common Table Expression). I'm building a derived table on the fly of all StaffingStartTimes and StaffingEndTimes. If you'd like, paste just the meaningfulDtms into a query window, and afterward "select * from meaningfulDtms".

Comment: Based on the OP's original query, I'm failing to appreciate the extra logic to track `timeType` and vary the comparisons. Wouldn't it suffice to get all of the distinct start and end times for each group and then verify that `dr.StaffingStartTime  <= meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime
     and dr.StaffingEndTime  > meaningfulDtms.meaningfulTime` regardless of `timeType`?

Comment: Bill: Ah, thank you!  It's missing the "With" keyword, which threw me (I haven't previously worked with CTEs).  I like your solution, it seems very efficient.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. You are right. I crafted it with my own CTE to mimic your DailyRosters table, and then just left it off when I pasted my answer in. Good luck.

Comment: Lastly, it appears that as written above, this misses an edge case if less than 4 staffing records exist for a group, all at the same start time.  For example, if I insert two rows into DailyRosters with a start time of 0800 today and end time of 0800 tomorrow morning, with the same group id and different personnel ids, no records are returned by the query above.  I modified < to <= and > to >= in the join clause which seems to address that.

Comment: Yes, I knew it wasn't perfect, but figured it would at least put you on the right track. The key is just realizing that you don't really have to test every minute of everyday. Just the "interesting" minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with all minutes in the day with dt at PK
It will have 1440 rows

this will not give you count of zero - no staff

```
select allMiuntes.dt, worktime.grpID, count(distinct(worktime.personID))
  from allMinutes 
  join worktime 
    on allMiuntes.dt > worktime.start 
   and allMiuntes.dt < worktime.end 
 group by allMiuntes.dt, worktime.grpID 
having count(distinct(worktime.personID)) < 3
```

for times with zero I think the best way is a master of grpID
but I am not sure about this one

```
select allMiuntes.dt, grpMaster.grpID, count(distinct(worktime.personID))
  from grpMaster
 cross join allMinutes 
  left join worktime 
    on allMiuntes.dt > worktime.start 
   and allMiuntes.dt < worktime.end 
   and worktime.grpID = grpMaster.grpID 
 group by allMiuntes.dt, grpMaster.grpID
having count(distinct(worktime.personID)) < 3
```

Comment: 24 * 60 = 1440? `allMiuntes`?